# What is `Cat.name` in NestJS mongoose docs?

Tags: nestjs

Reading the NestJS docs on the [MongoDB technique](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/mongodb), I've came along a confusing example:

```
@Injectable()
export class CatsService {
  constructor(@InjectModel(Cat.name) private catModel: Model<CatDocument>) {}

  async create(createCatDto: CreateCatDto): Promise<Cat> {
    const createdCat = new this.catModel(createCatDto);
    return createdCat.save();
  }

  async findAll(): Promise<Cat[]> {
    return this.catModel.find().exec();
  }
}
```

The line that confuses me is the constructor one; where to `@InjectModel` is given `Cat.name`. But, in the *cats.schema.ts* file, there's no inheritance from another class, nor any valorised static property with that name:

```
import { Prop, Schema, SchemaFactory } from '@nestjs/mongoose';
import { Document } from 'mongoose';

export type CatDocument = Cat & Document;

@Schema()
export class Cat {
  @Prop()
  name: string;

  @Prop()
  age: number;

  @Prop()
  breed: string;
}

export const CatSchema = SchemaFactory.createForClass(Cat);
```

Am I missing something or could it be a "bug" in the docs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Cat.name` in this case refers to the inherent static property `name` that all classes have (really all functions have). This gives us a built in constant that we can refer to without having to write our own, but if you'd prefer you can use the string `'Cat'` as well. In this case, `Cat.name` is the string `'Cat'`, just a different way to reference it that is built in to all classes (and functions).

[JavaScript docs on Function.name](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/name)

Comment: Ooooooh! Okk! So it was referring to **THAT** name. I was confused by the fact that cat itself had a name, and I was focused only on understanding how that property could be accessed without instantiation hahahahahahaha :D thank you for your clarification!